# Menu page with three columns

Tags: menus, dashboard

Seeing all the postbox-containers in wordpress i was wondering if there is a way to add a third column to a custom wordpress admin menu page.

I would like to have something like I get when using the col-md-4 from bootstrap but without bootstrap changing everything else in my dashboard.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid any core-related layout classes and just roll your own (you don't need bootstrap for this). In your PHP page handler, just kick out something like:

```
<div class="wrap">

    <div class="my-plugin-column">
       How...
    </div>

    <div class="my-plugin-column">
       you...
    </div>

    <div class="my-plugin-column">
       doin'?
    </div>

    <!-- And so forth -->

</div>
```

And then in your plugin CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
    .my-plugin-column {
        float: left;
        width: 30%;
    }

    /* first column */
    .my-plugin-column:nth-child(3n+1) {
        clear: left;
    }

    /* second and third columns */
    .my-plugin-column:nth-child(3n+2),
    .my-plugin-column:nth-child(3n+3) {
        margin-left: 5%;
    }
}
```

You could be even more advanced and display two columns at smaller breakpoint, before you switch to three for larger devices.

Comment: Thank you. I got this. Worked pretty neat. I am just trying to figure out if there is a way to use more of the content, as the margins are pretty big. 
Right now i changed the margin-left to 0.5% and the width to 33%. Is there any better solution?

Comment: The width should equal `( 100 - ( margin x 2 ) ) / 3`